# If statement simplification in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a line of code that looks like this:

```
if (obj is byte || obj is int || obj is long || obj is decimal || obj is double || obj is float)
```

Is it possible to write something more elegant than this? Something like:

```
if (obj is byte, int, long)
```

I know that my example isn't possible, but is there a way to make this look "cleaner"?

Comment: I wish your syntax was available. :-(

Comment: All this hackery just to get something to act like INumeric

Comment: It's not necessarily just for numeric types, I need to compare against custom types as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could write an extension method on object to give you syntax like:

```
if (obj.Is<byte, int, long>()) { ... }
```

Something like this (use multiple versions for fewer or more generic arguments:

```
public static bool Is<T1, T2, T3>(this object o)
{
    return o is T1 || o is T2 || o is T3;
}
```

Comment: I would name the method IsOneOf, but this is a very concise syntax indeed.

Comment: shame you can't use something like params for generic parameters

Comment: @Matthew, I wonder if one could define `interface ITuple` and then subclass it with a variety of tuple generic classes (`Tuple<T> : ITuple`, `Tuple<T1,T2> : ITuple`, etc). Then redo the extension method as `Is<TTuple> where TTuple : ITuple`.. Then unwrap the generic type arguments inside of the method.. This would give `params`-like generic argument functionality...

Answer (score 12):

Only:

```
static readonly HashSet<Type> types = new HashSet<Type> 
    { typeof(byte), typeof(int), typeof(long) etc };

...

if (types.Contains(obj.GetType())
{
}
```

Or use `obj.GetType().GetTypeCode()`.

Answer (score 8):

I would throw it into a method to simplify it a bit:

```
private static bool ObjIsNumber(object obj)
{
    return  (obj is byte || obj is int || obj is long || 
             obj is decimal || obj is double || obj is float);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Upvoting you.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do this?

```
bool IsRequestedType(object obj)
{
    if (obj is byte || obj is int || obj is long || obj is decimal || obj is double || obj is float)
         return true;
    return false;
}
```

Or you might be able to get away with

```
obj is IComparable
```

Comment: cmon, `if (true) return true; else return false;` - Ishy.

Comment: Or simply: 
bool IsRequestedType(object obj)
{
   return obj is byte || obj is int || obj is long || obj is decimal || obj is double || obj is float;
}

Comment: obj is IComparable would also allow string... probably not what he wants.

Comment: @arkain, that is what i did in my answer.

Comment: @ jinguy, hadn't scrolled that far down yet, when I wrote, I have upvoted you.

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine to me - nice and clear.

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper function to put your test in.

Something like

```
public static Boolean IsNumeric(Object myObject) {
    return (obj is byte || obj is int || obj is long || obj is decimal || obj is double|| obj is float);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool IsOneOf(object o, params Type[] types)
{
    foreach(Type t in types)
    {
        if(o.GetType() == t) return true;   
    }

    return false;
}

long l = 10;
double d = 10;
string s = "blah";

Console.WriteLine(IsOneOf(l, typeof(long), typeof(double))); // true
Console.WriteLine(IsOneOf(d, typeof(long), typeof(double))); // true
Console.WriteLine(IsOneOf(s, typeof(long), typeof(double))); // false
```